# Field Calculator Skipping Statement

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser

I am having trouble with a field calculator statement! I am trying to reclassify an attribute column based on their values. So if value =0 then make it 14, if value < 3 make it 11, if value >3 and < 9 then make it 12 and if none of the above make it 13.

I wrote this but 12 doesnt ever show up when i know it must!

My Code:

```
CODE BLOCK
def reclass(x):
     if x == 0:
          x = 14
     elif x <= 3:
          x = 11
     elif (x < 4 and x > 9):
          x = 12
     else:
          x = 13
     return x
field= reclass(attribute)
```

Comment: x can never be both less than 4 and greater than 9 at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
elif (x < 4 and x > 9):
```

with

```
elif (x >3 and x < 9):
```